# Is it possible to remove square brackets from ImmutableMultimap.keys()

Tags: java, guava

While performing the following:

```
ImmutableMultimap<Something, Something> map;
//Say I insert "Hello", "5" to the map
System.out.println(map.keys().toString());
```

This prints `[Hello]` So when I do

```
if(map.keys().toString().equals("Hello"))
```

it always fails. I don't want to do

```
if(map.keys().toString.equals("[Hello]")
```

Is there a way to display the result without the square brackets?

Comment: Are you always going to add just 1 element? Because if you add more then it will have commas and spaces. e.g. `[Hello, World]`. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @BheshGurung: Well, I can take care of the commas, but the brackets are my concern.

Comment: Thre `replace(oldChar, newChar)` might be useful - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char, char)

Comment: @veer: What you said will give me true for `"OOOOO"` too.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Because I think you are going the wrong way.

Comment: @noMAD what do you mean? It checks to see if the entire map size is solely due to `"Hello"` and is non-empty, which implies `map.keys().toString()` equals `"[Hello]"`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: My basic goal was to compare the objects in the map to other objects and see if they are the same. I just gave an example above. Am writing a test case where I want to `assertEquals(map.keys(),MyObject)`

Comment: Please realise that keys() returns a Set, if you want to check equality, then MyObject needs to be a Set as well containing the key or keys.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel actually `keys` returns a `Multiset`, which specifies that [`equals` will only be true when compared to other `Multiset`s with the same frequency per element](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html#equals(java.lang.Object)).

Comment: @veer You are right, I was thinking of keySet() from a normal Map.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should never ever use `toString()` for anything serious! This method is meant for people inspecting what's going on (e.g. in debugger) and for nothing else.

Moreover, there are no brackets there in. `map.keys()` is a collection and it's `toString()` method works like it should for collections. You'd better replace your test by testing `map.keys.size() == 1` and then checking the only element.

Comment: Moreover, the exact format of `Multiset.toString()` is [unspecified](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html#toString()), so it could change in future releases, breaking your code -- and it'd deserve to get broken.  =/

Comment: saying `toString()` should **never** be used is rather categorical ;) Actually there are legitimate use cases. It is better to say that `toString()` should never be used unless the API you are calling specifically defines what you should expect to get out. e.g. `StringBuilder.toString()` is safe to use, `Collection.toString()` is not.

Comment: @fommil: Agreed, `CharSequence.toString()` is an important exception to this rule.

Answer (score 5):

```
map.keys().toString().replaceAll("[\\[\\],]","")
```

returns the string, all square brackets and commas removed

Comment: I don't know but I think its because of what maaarinus answered.

Comment: I hope it's not... this answer does what was requested (instead of explaining that it shouldn't be done at all). However, removing all brackets (instead of just the enclosing ones) goes a bit too far, IMHO. Maybe that's why.

Comment: (I'm not the downvoter, but...) It may seem like what the questioner asked for, but it's such a fragile solution. Consider when the keys are "Maine", "Vermont", and "New York".  Now you have the string "Maine Vermont New York". What good is that?

Comment: Haha, I'll agree that what he's trying to do seems kind of meaningless to me, but I just assumed he had a good reason for asking, and provided what I thought was the answer!

Answer (score 2):

If you're checking for equality like in a test you should really be doing this instead:

```
System.out.println(ImmutableMultiSet.of("Hello").equals(map.keys()))
```

Since ImmutableMultiSet has a correct implementation of .equals, that should deal with all the possible cases there besides map being null.

---

If you want a String containing all the elements in it then use Joiner instead:

```
System.out.println(Joiner.on(",").join(map.keys()))
```

There's a lot more options on Joiner for the various ways it can format the collection.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the brackets in the string, or you could iterate through the key set and print each component individually.

```
 ImmutableMultiset<Something> keys = map.keys();
 for(Something key : keys){
    System.out.print(key);
 }
```

For your conditionals you would want

```
if(map.keys().contains("Hello"))
```

Comment: keySet() returns the result in the same way. I didn't want to modify the string, that's why I asked the question.

Comment: @noMAD that isn't string contains it is the contains method on the collection.

Comment: @noMAD keys is a collection of more than one object. It sees if the collection contains the string `"Hello"` not does it contain a string which has `"Hello"` as part of it.

Comment: Thanks, used it in a different sort of way, but it helped :)

Comment: Even better for the conditionals: `if (map.containsKey("Hello"))`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer if you only want the first element

map.keys()[0]

Comment: It might improve your answer to additionally show how the code looks with your change.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked a very long time ago but someone would help with this answer. So try this out !

```
map.keys(item => item)[0]
```